# Running :make from gVim in Background

Tags: compilation, vim

I use gVim in windows to edit my code (mostly C++). I use :make in gVim to compile the project, but this is a blocking operation, that prevents me from using gVim until the compilation is complete. How can I do :make asynchronously and still get the benefits of reading the errors back into Vim and jump to the errors in source code? Bonus points if I get to see the make process in real time. Right now the :make redirects the output into a file, hence I don't get to see the progress of make.

Comment: did u find a good solution for this

Comment: @pydave created a plugin called AsyncCommand which achieves most of the items listed in the question except seeing the make process in action.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What I do is

```
:!gvim -c 'MyMake'
```

( where MyMake is the custom command which can switch to appropriate dir, make, and copen 20. )

and I am doing my job while build goes in the other window.

**Other option:**
You can redirect make progress to some file from the shell or within vim (:!make&). And then by using

```
:cfile make_result_file

:cw
 or
:copen 20
```

Achieve the same result as you'd use :make

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your MyMake command? I'm trying to do something similar with gvim on windows and msbuild (i.e., launch external gvim window, make, and open output) but I can't get the command right.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at @tpope's dispatch.vim

https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch#readme

Video Trailer: http://vimeo.com/63116209

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at my [AsyncCommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3431) plugin. It's just wraps the vim syntax required to execute something and load it with --remote. I've uploaded AsyncCommand 2.0 that includes an `AsyncMake` command.

Add the script to your `.vim/plugin` and you can build with `:AsyncMake` or `:AsyncMake target`. Errors will be opened in your quickfix once the make completes.

---

Responding to comment for more readable code:

To see the build results on Windows, if you have [cygwin](http://cygwin.org)/[unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)/something with [tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)) in your path, then in asynccommand.vim, change

```
call <SID>Async_Impl(tool_cmd, vim_cmd)
```

to

```
call <SID>Async_Impl(tool_cmd, vim_cmd)
call <SID>Async_Impl("tail -f ". temp_file, "")
```

That should change all Async commands to open up a second command window with the output.

Comment: Hey thanks for making that plugin. Is there a way to see the make process in action? I'm using Win XP and the command window is blank until the make process is complete then the quickfix window opens.

Comment: I forgot that the command window shows nothing. I've modified the answer to give a potential workaround.

Comment: I added the lines you mentioned above, but I still have blank command window. I'm in Window XP and I do have tail in my path. I even included the full path to the tail command.

Comment: I don't have a Win machine to test on, but you could try replacing the line with `printf` with `let tool_cmd = a:command . "| tee ". temp_file`   However you might need to add `2>&1` before tee to see any stderr output.

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
:!start make
```

(more info on ":help !start") - that way vim doesn't have to wait for the process started to finish - you can just keep on going with your editing).

Comment: :!start make  works fine if you are just trying to spawn a make process. I am looking to use the in build feature of gvim where it reads the errors into vim and you can jump to the error in source code by double clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use your OS's inbuilt methods for running background tasks.

On windows, try typing

```
:!start make
```

On linux / mac os x, try

```
:!make > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: :!start make  works fine if you are just trying to spawn a make process. I am looking to use the in build feature of gvim where it reads the errors into vim and you can jump to the error in source code by double clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to see the progress of make (within Vim) unless you install a very recent version of Vim (v7.4 and many patches, or simply Vim 8). Now there are a few plugins that've taken advantage of it. My [BuildToolsWrapper](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper) is one of them. I've tested it successfully on linux and on windows.

Before that we needed other tricks. I remember Marc Weber's plugin which was able to emulate background compilation on Windows. There was a few others. I let others list them.

Answer (score -1):

see [this script](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=3479)

Comment: That script is not usable on Windows.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.