# Is it possible to call :make in vim in linux without showing the shell

Tags: vim

I've been trying to experiment with using `:make` recently but I don't like that vim has to switch to showing the shell output first and require one enter keypress, then it shows me what I think is a list of the collected errors based on `'errorformat'` which I also need to confirm by pressing enter. I would prefer to just have a short "OK" message that does not require confirmation by a keypress, or that vim would open the `:cwindow` if there were any errors.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [Running :make from gVim in Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666453/running-make-from-gvim-in-background/666578#666578).

Comment: This question apparently is about running `make` in **foreground** and jump directly to the first error found after `make` finishes, without hassle and prompts which unnecessarily slow down development.  (`make` often takes a millisecond to hit the first error and stop.  So why run it in background?)

Answer (score 17):

I'm using next line just for exact purpose you wrote:

```
nnoremap <leader>m :silent make\|redraw!\|cc<CR>
```

`cc` in the end shows first error or `No errors` message if this is the case.

Comment: Great idea! However, I prefer not to be taken automatically to the location of the first error, but only be shown the quickfix window in case of errors, so I changed to `make!\|redraw!\|cw<CR>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
:silent make
```

To automatically open the quickfix window after you run `make`, you can put this into your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost * :copen
```

Comment: I already tried :silent make but it just makes the vim window completely black (vim's command line and laststatus is still shown) so I have to call :make to get the buffer to be shown in the window again.

Answer (score 2):

You can map for example F9 to use gcc for small C snippets that don't require libraries, linking, etc:

```
map <F9> :!gcc -o %< % <enter><CR><C-w>
```

This will produce for the file `foo.c` the binary `foo`. I know that's not exactly what you want, but this doesn't show any shell and is useful for small c snippet.