# Silent make execution in vim/gvim

Tags: makefile, vim

I want to use gvim to launch make and do the build for my code. Since the build process takes some time i want it to be silently executed and then in the end errors/build log be showed to me.

i have added this to my .vimrc

```
:command -nargs=* Make silent make <args>  | cwindow 10
map <c-b> <c-o>:Make<cr>
```

So when i press Ctrl-b it starts building. But when i do that my gvim hangs and i cant do anything for sometime. Is there a way to accomplish what i am trying to do.

Since i am using `cwindow 10` at the end of make , it launches the quickfix window. In addition to that i also want to see the build log. Can i somehow do that

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666453/running-make-from-gvim-in-background

Comment: also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089028/is-it-possible-to-call-make-in-vim-in-linux-without-showing-the-shell

Answer (score 0):

As I said in similar questions: Have a look at my [AsyncCommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3431) plugin. Add the script to your `.vim/plugin` and you can build with `:AsyncMake` or `:AsyncMake target`. Errors will be opened in your quickfix once the make completes.

---

For the log file, you could extend AsyncMake to also open the build log. Add this to your vimrc after you've installed asynccommand.vim:

```
function! AsyncMakeWithLog(target)
    let make_cmd = &makeprg ." ". a:target
    let vim_func = "OnCompleteLoadErrorAndLog"
    call AsyncCommand(make_cmd, vim_func)
endfunction
" Load the output as an error file and load the full build log
function! OnCompleteLoadErrorAndLog(temp_file_name)
    call OnCompleteLoadErrorFile(a:temp_file_name)
    call OnCompleteLoadFile(a:temp_file_name)
endfunction
```

**However**, the log file and the error window will have a lot of the same text, so you don't always need both. If your build tool already writes its build log to disk, then I'd suggest you have the build output include the full path to the build log. That way you can type `gf` on the path in the error window to jump to the build log when necessary.