# Run compilation in vim cwindow (and have vim not being "frozen")

Tags: bash, vim, compilation

I use vim as my IDE and I also compile with it. I don't like the fact that vim is "frozen" when you run a (terminal) command inside of it.

So what I was trying to do is running my compilation in a [conqueterm](http://code.google.com/p/conque/) and have it outputed in a file (in `/tmp/`) and then open it with `cwindow`. This is a bit far fetched I agree but the idead is here.

For now I'm using this command (binded to `<F8>`) but it takes my vim and i can't edit anything while it's compiling...

```
command -nargs=* BuildThat make -C /my_build_dir -j <args> | botright cwindow 3
```

So how do you vimers do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim can't run asynchronous tasks by default. There are a bunch of scripts written to work around this limitation:

- [shellasync](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4182)
- [vim-addon-async](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3307)
- [AsyncCommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3431)

Comment: In the end I was having my problem in the wrong way here is what i wanted to do : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412785/silent-make-execution-in-vim-gvim Thanks for your help :) I'm using AsyncCommand now.