# How to continue editing file when making?

Tags: vim, editor, makefile

I use `:make` to make project in vim.

What I would like to know is how to continue editing the current project in `vim` while making. The `make` of the project always consumes a lot of time, so every time `vim` runs `make`, I have nothing to do except wait for it to complete making. Using this time to check the file is quite good.

Comment: That's your chance to catch up on SO questions and answers...

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666453/running-make-from-gvim-in-background

Comment: Sorry, i haven't found this thread before. But i found that these two solutions is not very perfect. So i doubt whether my demand is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin [AsyncCommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3431)

You need to start gvim or vim with --servername  option. Then you can use command :AsyncMake

Comment: When i use this plugin to async make, i found that the screen will be blank when the make is going. It means that i am actually stay in vim, but the code will disappear.