# Detaching process from gvim

Tags: vim

Whenever I run my program (i.e. `:make`) from gvim the process is attached to it. I.e. I cannot do anything in vim without terminating my process.

Is there a way to run the process without having to close it to continue editing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and dirty hack for you to do that is to change `makeprg` into `make 2>&1 > ~/make.log &` which shall fork the make command and ouptuts stdout/stderr in `~/make.log`. Then you can edit ~/make.log to get the output in a new buffer.

I know there are plugins that can do that kind of things too, but I have to google that to find them again. Last solution to make your makeprg execute a remote command in a tmux or screen session.

you may also have a look at [Running :make from gVim in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666453/running-make-from-gvim-in-background)

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it myself but Tim Pope has created a plugin to launch tasks in the background called [Vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch).

There is a video showing some typical use case : launching some syntax checker, or unit test, while keeping an active window to keep editing.

I think this is a great addition, because it is, or was, one of Vim weakness.