# Vim :make, :grep making shell fg first

Tags: vim

I have VIM 7.4 MacOS X version. Huge version without GUI. I use zsh in the Terminal app.

Recently I discovered `:make` and `:grep` which are just awesome! However, this is one small annoyance in using them in my compile-edit-run loop. When I see video's of people using these commands, it doesn't happen to them - so it must be something I need to setup.

When I run these commands like `:make | copen`, vim doesn't **first** just open a quickfix window with the errors. The **first** thing vim does is jump back to the shell and display the compiler output there. Then I have to `<Enter>` through one (sometimes two) screens before I get back to vim with the quickfix window open.

I know this is small.... but it's super annoying when it happens literally every compile.

Comment: Not a solution, but an alternative take... you know about the [Conque](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) plugin offering the ability to run a terminal *as Vim buffer*? Also, [this Vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_open_the_quickfix_window_on_:make)...

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks for the response! Ya I saw that Vim tip - but it still shows the compiler output in the shell first :(

Comment: @PeterRincker Thank you! I honestly don't know how I haven't stumbled across those - I've been searching for hours!

Comment: My comment was removed so here are the similar SuperUser posts: [Vim: :silent with makeprg](http://superuser.com/questions/501908/vim-silent-with-makeprg) and [VIM: Don't pause after `make`](http://superuser.com/q/381840). The related StackOverflow post is here: [Running :make from gVim in Background](http://stackoverflow.com/q/666453/438329) (Note I prefer the dispatch solution on that question).